# How to find a parent of a node in a Binary Tree?

Tags: java, tree

I have a tree that was converted from a general tree to a binary tree:

```
                   B
                  /
                 A
                  \
                   D
                  / \
                 /   I
                /   /
               C    H
                \    \
                 E    L
                  \
                   G 
                  /
                 F
```

that means the following:

- B is the root, its children are A, D, I
- D's children are C, E, G
- I's children are H, L

and so on.

Now, I have to write the following method:

```
public Position<E> parent(Position<E> v)
```

Where "v" represents one of the letters in the above tree, and this method needs to find its parent.

I've been struggling with this for hours.. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't look like a binary tree at all.

Comment: It's because it was a general tree at first, and it was converted to a binary tree. That's how you represent a general tree, that has some nodes with 3 children (in this case), as a binary tree.

Comment: From the concept of Binary tree, a node can only have 2 children, not 3.

Comment: Yeah, but if you look up how to convert a general tree to a binary tree you would see what i mean. That's just how it's done..

Comment: I don't follow you. If you convert any tree to a binary tree, you will get a tree where a node can have at most 2 nodes as children, and depending on your implementation the rest of the children nodes will become children for other nodes in the tree and will have a common ancestor. Again, I'm not sure about how you can do something like this. Provide more info about the specific rules you (have to) use to convert your N-children tree to a binary tree, then we can help you.

Comment: Well the tree that i presented doesn't have more than 2 children per node.. 

But the general tree-to-binary-tree-conversion rule is that you put all of the node's children to its left, and if it has any siblings they would be on its right.

So if you look at my tree, you see how I is to the right of D which is to the right of A? that means they're all siblings (same level).

Comment: Simple: traverse over the tree till you find your target node as a left or right of some other node.

Comment: yeah and then what? how do i "get back up" to its parent once i find it? because if that node is to the right of some node, it doesn't mean it's its parent.

Comment: You need  to give the members of `Position` for anyone to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: It's just an on object containing a String value, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same homework as you...

For the solution,
A parent in our general tree will be a node in our binary tree that has one left child and that the right child of this parent is not equal to our node v.(see the node I)

You can work on this:  if the parent of v as a left child then the parent of v will be the last found node with a left child. But the parent must not have a right child so if it has one, you must search for the upper parent of this last node.(see the node I)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

from what you shown:

algorithm is:

```
start from root

for every node v

every left-child is node v's child so add this child to node v childs list

every right-child is node v's parent's child(or parent of parent until it is a left-child of its parent, then the node you discovered is the child of left-child node's parent's child).
```

pseudo code  for finding a node's parent in actual tree:

```
enter node.

if node is left child
    print its node->parent.
else
    while node->parent is right child
       node = node->parent
    print node->parent.
```

Comment: Yeah what you wrote perfectly describes the nodes, but how can i implement a code that finds the parent of a given node?..

Comment: You want parent of a node in binary tree or in actual tree?

Comment: @Gambit2007 since I like your question I'm going to give you the pseudo code, but I'm not going to spoonfood you and give the whole answer

Comment: We don't usually have the access to the parent of a node. only its left and right.

Comment: thank you very much but i don't really understand it.. i've only seen a couple of pseudo codes in my life. what does the notation -> mean?

and what is "node" equal to in the first line?.. is it equal at first to the node whose parent i'm trying to find?

Comment: @seteropere yeah I know, and in the algorithm I give him a approach to find every child of every node(and so every parent of every node) but he insist to find a parent of a given node, and I just assume that he have every nodes parent in binary tree.

Comment: @Gambit2007 I'm sorry I didnt see your question is in java, in c and c++ it is like what node.parent do, but for pointer, just ignore it. what I mean is in while loop, replace node with it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple; assuming your Node class does not have access to the parent  i.e.

```
class Node{
Node left;
Node right;
int value;
}
```

All you need to do is to start from the root and traverse over the tree in a `pre-order` fashion. If you encounter your target node then its parent is one of the last two elements popped from the Stack (why?)

@See [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of binary tree it's simplest to relabel the child pointers as `children` (left child) and `sibling` (right child) because that's what they represent.  Since you don't have parent pointers, when you find a node that might be a parent, you must pass it on as you search future nodes.

I need to make lots of assumptions because you gave so little information.

If `Position` is your node type and your desired function is member of a `Tree`, then then it will look something like:

```
private Position<E> parentImpl(Position<E> v, Position<E> node, Position<E> parent) {

  if (node.equals(v)) {
    return parent;
  } 

  for (Position<E> child = v.children; child != null; child = child.sibling) {
    Position<E> rtn = parentImpl(v, child, node);  // current node is parent
    if (rtn != null) {
      return rtn;
    }
  }        
  return null;
}
```

Now the function you want just calls this one.

```
public Position<E> parent(Position<E> v) {
  return parentImpl(v, root, null);  // Root has no parent.
}
```

This will return null both when v is not in the tree at all and when it's the root of the tree.

Comment: public Position<E> parent(Position<E> v) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    
return parentImpl(v, bTree.root(), null);

  }
  
  private Position<E> parentImpl(Position<E> v, Position<E> node, Position<E> parent) {

  if (node == v) {
    return parent;
  } 

  for (Position<E> child = bTree.left(v); child != null; child = bTree.right(v)) {
    Position<E> rtn = parentImpl(v, child, node);
    if (rtn != null) {
      return rtn;
    }
  }        
  return null;
}


That's how i implemented it and it didn't work..
bTree.left(v) is how you access the child, bTree.right(v) for the sibling

Comment: Man, you didn't give anywhere near enough information to provide a perfect solution.  I said "something like," not "this is it."  Figure out what my code is doing and find your bug.  I guarantee this approach will work.